# How do I install Frank when my project is using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, frank

I have a sample, new project that and I used `Cocoapods` to install `TestFlight` and `RestKit`.  Now I am trying to add Frank but "frank build" does not work.

I've tried following steps listed [here](http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/10/16/frank-with-cocoapods/);

I've tried to modify the franked `../Frank/frankify.xcconfig` and I've modified the `.xcconfig` for the default target.

When I run "frank build", the build fails and leaves me a message, `"ld: library not found for -lPods"`.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

from the article you link to, after modifying your `frankify.xcconfig` file, you still have to call frank with the `--workspace` and `--scheme` flags.

Answer (score 2):

just type

```
frank build --workspace YourWorkspace.xcworkspace/ --scheme YourProject
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have this problem because the scheme is missing for the Pods project that provides this library. You need to tweak the build script/Frank to use the new xcworkspace instead of the original xcodeproj file. Changing that should get you your normal project and the Pods static library it depends on.

This also happens with Jenkins and Hudson builds too. The problem isn't isolated to just Frank.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with the following in the command line;  'frank build --workspace workspace_name.xcworkspace --scheme scheme_name'

Comment: That actually didn't work.  It was able to build but when I try to use RestKit, the RestKit framework I installed with Cocoapods, cannot be found.

Comment: You will likely need to make sure your build schemes are shared so that the code gets built and included. There are build scripts added by CP to build the Pod project first and then the original project dynamically links to the created static library. So that isn't going to change, it's just a matter of getting the build schemes right.